# Smtplib fails sending email from mail.ru

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I use smtplib to send emails using this code:

```
file = "path_to_a_file"
part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
part.set_payload(open(file, "rb").read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(file_book))
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = from_email@example.com
msg['To'] = to_email@example.com
msg.attach(part)
smtp = SMTP_SSL()
smtp.connect('smtp.yandex.ru')
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.login('my_email@yandex.ru', 'pass')
try:
    smtp.sendmail('my_email@yandex.ru', 'to_email@example.com', msg.as_string())
except SMTPException as e:
    print("Error: unable to send email: "+str(e))
smtp.quit()
```

If I use either `*@yandex.ru` or `*@gmail.com` or `*@my_domain.info` as `msg['From']` it works just fine. Don't change anything, just pretending the email is being sent from the specified address. But if I'm trying to use `*@mail.ru` (some shitty email service) I get smtplib exception with this error:

```
 (554, b'5.7.0 Failed to authorize the sender 1505621397-z6HZZunef2-9ulCCxTQ 1505621397-ZhCGNIKkSZ-9uPOg8fd')
```

Why does smtplib behaves differently if there is no authorisation credentials changes made?

Comment: Seems like it's not smtplib that behaves wrong, it's a server's response. So I'm doing somthing wrong composing the email?

Comment: So changing the mail server solves the issue.